# Cannot free memory of or unload flash swf

Tags: actionscript-3, memory, jquery-animate, adobe

I'm using Adobe Animate CC with AS3. I'm having the following problem with my project (which has a lot of animation in it and hence is quite heavy)

There are 4 swf files which are in the same folder. The first one is like a blank container which loads the second swf automatically upon run. The second one has got a few buttons in it along with some animation. When the animation gets over, there is a button that loads the third swf. Now this 3rd swf has got a next button to load the next swf. The 4th swf has got back button to load the previous swf. The 3rd swf has in turn a home button that loads the 2nd swf. 
Now, the problem is that when the next button is pressed, say on 2nd swf, not only should the 3rd swf open but the 2nd swf should get unloaded and the memory occupied by it should be freed. And same with the 3rd and the 4th swf. 
However, the unloaded swf should open again when the back button is clicked.
If anyone could provide a link to or code for back button and load-unload, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is much easier to load them all at once and then switch their visibility/attachment to the stage. However, if they are indeed too heavy to reside in the memory at once, you need a little trick to load them into a separate **ApplicationDomain** so they could be removed without anything left behind.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;

var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;

// Loading an SWF so it can be fully unloaded.
aLoader.load(new URLRequest("external.swf"), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain));

// Unloading the loaded SWF.
aLoader.unloadAndStop(true);
```